# Soundtrack Variations Per DVD Zone?

Tags: soundtrack, distribution

In terms of DVD zoning, I am in **Zone 4**.

I noticed a tune being played in **S1E12** of *The Sopranos* when Tony was driving his car. It was extremely Stevie Ray Vaughan-ish, but as much as I searched for SRV tunes that might match, I couldn't locate it.

I did a search too for all the songs used during the episode and couldn't find a single one that matched. After a discussion on-line with someone from America, I was told what the tune was that THEY heard while watching the episode in **Zone 1**. It was *clearly* a different tune.

I'm familiar with changes in films in many areas between zones, most notably, with titles. *The Lucky Number Slevin* is called *The Wrong Man* in my country. But this is the first I'd come across of a tune in a TV show being different between zones.

*My question in two parts:*

**A) Has anyone else come across such a soundtrack change?**

**B) What would be some possible reasons for such a change?**

Regarding B), I'm ok with reasonably educated guesses at this point because I'm not sure we'll get an authoritative reason.

Comment: Well, music licensing does vary between regions. Chock it up to that.